# Gitkraken Commits coming through as different user

Tags: git, version-control

I am using git kraken and I am signed in using github. When I do this I get success Github is linked with Git Kraken message.

My commits push to my repos on github just fine however they come up under my real name, and not my github profile name. Basically its like the same account has two different users on it somehow.[The image with the logo is a commit from Github, no image is from gitkraken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwXRC.png) The main issue is that no commits from gitkraken are counting to my contribution history which is not ideal. Im not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I don't use Git kraken. What email did you configure for committing/authoring? With plain `git`, I do `git config user.email <email-used-in-github>`.

Comment: This was the correct answer. Git kraken for some reason had a different profile active that was using a different email. Thank you for this. Kinda annoying considering I was logged into the actual github account it would allow that, maybe it has use cases im not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

@muru  was Correct. Git Kraken has profiles you can select in the top right hand corner. There it will show your commit signiture, mine email was not the same as my github one. I changed it and now commits show up properly.